# Adding delay to the output in Verilog

Tags: verilog, delay, fpga

I need to add a synthesizable delay in my code to get an output. My code is:

```
   module square_wave(clk,rst,dac_out);
   input clk; 
   input rst;
   output reg dac_out;
   reg [3:0]  counter; // 

   always @(posedge clk)
     begin
        if (rst == 1'b1  ||  counter == 4'b1111) // period, count from 0 to n-1
          counter <= 0;
        else
          counter <= counter + 1'b1;

        if (rst == 1'b0  &&  counter < 4'b0110) // duty cycle, m cycles high
          dac_out = 1'b1;
        else
          dac_out = 1'b0;
      end
endmodule
```

This gives me an output where 6 out of the 15 times of the initial clock cycle, it will be 1, and otherwise 0. So far, it is good. But the other signal I need, TG, needs to be kinda twice of this signal. Meaning in 15 cycles, it should be 1 2 times.
So, what I need to do is delay my output signal by 6 or 7 or 8 times the original clock cycle so that I get a delayed signal, which I can then add to my original output to get what I need. Please refer to the image attached. I am unable to figure out the synthesizable delay. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
[Please look at this pic to help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afphb.png)

[image]

Comment: Start with stating your requirements: "I need a signal of X K/MHz to be delay by Y Nano/Micro seconds." Then specify what you have: "I have available the following clock(s) A, B, C."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shift register to delay your output the required number of cycles. Then OR the original output with the delayed output

```
 module square_wave(
   input clk, rst,
   output regdac_out, 
   output TG);
   reg [3:0]  counter;
   reg [7:0] shifter;
   always @(posedge clk)
        if (rst == 1'b1  ||  counter == 4'b1111) // period, count from 0 to n-1
          counter <= 0;
        else begin
          counter <= counter + 1'b1;
          shifter <= {shifter, dac_out};
          if (rst == 1'b0  &&  counter < 4'b0110) // duty cycle, m cycles high
            dac_out <= 1'b1;
          else
            dac_out <= 1'b0;
        end
   assign TG = dac_out || shifter[7];
endmodule
```

If that's not what you want, you need to give us a much better idea of what the waveform looks like. You picture does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You may add delays by instantiating a delay buffer from the standard cell library if you want custom delays (i.e. delay != N(1/clk)). But please note that you may have to add dont_touch option while synthesizing because the tool may optimize the delay buffer since there is no logic in the data path of the buffer (capacitors are used to delay the signal).
Or you may use D-Flops shown below to delay (here delay value = N(1/clk))your signal.

```
 always@(posedge clk)    
 begin
  data1_d1 <= data1;       //Delay data1 by one clock (clk)
  data1_d2 <= data1_d1;    //Delay data1 by two clocks (clk)
 end
```